# Multisite with subdomain and subdirectory addresses

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, ip-address, subdirectory, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite that uses subdomain addresses. I would like to have some of those subsites to use subdirectories instead. Is it possible?

Example:

site1.example.com

site2.example.com -> I'd like this to be example.com/site2

site3.example.com -> I'd like this to be example.com/site3

site4.example.com

Comment: Can’t you set up the URL to be used for each site in the respective dashboard individually?

Comment: Not that I know. There is a premium plugin that does domain mapping but I'm looking for something that is build in WordPress before trying to solve my problem with plugins https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping/